# Overline in Probablity and Statistics?

Tags: statistics, notation

I'm having trouble finding concise information about this. What does the overline in probability and statistics mean?

After looking around for a bit i found out it could be a complement, as in $\overline A\cap B = \text{"Not $A$ and $B$"}$  which I found is usually written as $A'\cap B$ but is sometimes written is many different ways. But if it does mean the same as $'$, then what does the double overline mean?

Examples:
$$ \overline{A}\cap B;
\qquad \overline{A}\cup B;
\qquad \overline{\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}}.$$

Comment: Assuming your defintion of overline as complement, which seems the only reasonable definition in this context, then $\overline{\left(\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}\right)} = (A^c \cap B^c)^c$. You can use DeMorgan's laws to rewrite this in a simpler form.

Comment: Alright thank you very much.

Comment: That is *set* notation (union, intersection), presumably they are talking about events (sets of possible outcomes). Note that often it is written $\overline{x}$ to symbolize the average of the sampled random variable $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The overline here is not being used in the sense of probability and statistics<sup>[1]</sup>, but in the sense of set theory.  In set theory, the overline typically denotes the *complement* of a set.  In this context,
$$ \overline{\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}}$$
is the complement of the set obtained by taking the intersection of the complements of $A$ and $B$.  Expanding things out a little, define the set
$$ C = \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}.$$
In words, $C$ is the set of all things which are contained in neither $A$ nor $B$.  Then
$$ \overline{\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}} = \overline{C} = \{ x : x\not\in C \}.$$
A "prime" is also often used for the set complement, e.g. $A'$, though there is potential that this notation could be confused with the derivative, or with some notion of duality.  My own preference is to use $A^\complement$ to denote the complement of a set, as this notation is not (to my knowledge) used anywhere else in mathematics, and so it has very little likelihood of being confusing or ambiguous.  With this notation,
$$ \overline{\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}} = \left( A^\complement \cap B^\complement \right)^\complement. $$

---

[1] In statistics, the overline typically denotes the *sample mean*.  That is, if we take a random sample from a population, and measure some statistic (say, $x_n$ is the height of the $n$-th person sampled), then $\overline{x}$ denotes the mean of sampled measurements, i.e.
$$ \overline{x} = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \dotsb + x_n}{n}. $$